# How to load multiple models with GLTF than fire a custom start() function?

Tags: three.js

The idea is to load all models first than set their relationships(child/parent), scale..etc. inside
a Start function. Than start the animate when its all ready.

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load(path,function(gltf){
   obj = gltf.scene;
   obj.name = name; 
   scene.add(obj);

});
```

when all models loaded

```
start();
```

when start finishes

```
function update(){

renderer.render(scene,camera);
requestAnimationFrame(update);}
```

I want to avoid check if loaded objects ==null

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of solving this issue is the usage of [THREE.LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager). This class allows you to keep track of loaded and pending data even when using multiple loader instances.

Try to implement the logic from your `start()` method inside the `onLoad()` callback.